# How to insert formula into cell

Tags: vba, excel

Please assist me with the following code. I'm not sure why I keep getting the error: **expected end of statement**

> Range("E" & i).Formula = "=""19""&Left(D" & i &"; 2)&""/"" & Mid(D" & i&"; 3; 2)&""/"" &Right(D" & i&";2)"

Comment: Try to copy your string in Immediate Window or `Debug.Print()` this string. You will see that some quotes is missing.

Comment: Have you tried deconstructing the code? Like break it into little bites and see where the error appears on the woekbook/sheet?

Comment: I haven't tried deconstructing yet but will try that now. Hi, Makah, how do you use the Debug.Print()?

Comment: @user3129445, please tell us what end result you want the Formula to be.

Answer (score 0):

You have both a quote and an ampersand problem.  Here is what is probably the correct line (can't be sure since you didn't tell us the desired end result).  Note that I put spaces around all of the unquoted ampersands.

> Range("E" & i).Formula = "=""19""&Left(D" & i & "; 2)&" & """/"" & Mid(D" & i & "; 3; 2)&" & """/"" &Right(D" & i & ";2)"